# Why do we need directives in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a newbie in angularJS so those who read this, may feel this as a silly question.

But the answers for the question that google returns is not actually answering my question.

The below link says services should use when the application grows.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398741/angularjs-controller-vs-service)

Fine. If so, services will be the option for larger application.

As per my understanding, Directive is nothing but a angular block which can be use for DOM manipulation.

Why should I choose this when I can do the same in services?

Should I use directive whenever I need to perform database operations and fill the data back to the html controls?

If i want to make REST API calls from angular, where I should write those methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AngularJS **directives** allow us to literally "direct" AngularJS to associate user-defined behaviors with a DOM element - giving great flexibility in creating and using custom elements in Web applications.

Whereas, **Services** are to serve. You make services to serve the repetitive and tedious tasks which you do not want to repeat in every controller (the part of application code interacting with view directly).

> If i want to make REST API calls from angular, where I should write
>   those methods?

Well,

You can see built-in services for example **[ng-resources](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)**, which helps make easy api calls to server i.e ajax calls.

Comment: what will be the order of execution for this? whether it will be module>>services>>directive or vice versa? Which will call the REST API?

Comment: @user1357872 There is no order, you dont have to use directives for making API call, you can use services. Assume if you want to do some DOM manipulation. say you want to print 'Hello world' 5 times using one directive element. You can go for directive

Comment: you need to write the respective method inside the service

Answer (score 1):

You can use directives to create your own HTML element, attribute, class or comment that does something special. You can even let others reuse this directive.

Let's say, I want a directive that automatically selects all text as soon as I click on the input box. Let's call this directive `select-all`. Let's say, this is an attribute directive.

If I used this directive, my DOM would look like

```
<input type='text' select-all></input>
```

That's it. You don't need to know where the code for `select-all` is sitting. You don't have to worry about anything related to how it works. Just insert the attribute `select-all` in any element you want and it works like magic.

That's the beauty of directives. You use it to create reusable web components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please help me to understand where I should write the method, If i want to make a REST API call from Angular?

Comment: `$http` service is used to make REST calls. It's a core service, so you don't have to install any libraries.

Like any other service you have to
1. Inject $http service in your controller or service
2. Call methods inside $http service to make your REST api.

Check out the documentation for $http service.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to provided answer, when thinking about creating a new directive, think about creating a component instead:

- configuration is slightly easier
- some best practices are enforced
- promotes component-based architecture
- prepares for the future: more compatible to how Angular 2 works

More information can be found in the [components documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component), where you can find out how to build a component step by step.

For calling a REST API, you can use the `$http` service. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). It is exhaustive, so I recommend the quick start from [here](http://techfunda.com/howto/565/http-post-server-request).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the use of a `Service` and a `Controller` to make REST calls.

```
// the controller
(function(ng, undefined){
        "use strict";
            ng.module("app").controller('MyController', ['$scope',  'MyService', 
                function($scope, MyService){

                    $scope.myModel = {};// where you store your data

                    // call the service to retrieve data
                    MyService.getResourcesDataById( 187, function (result) {
                        $scope.myModel.data = result; // assign result
                    });
            }]);
})(angular);

// the service
(function(ng, undefined){
    "use strict";
        ng.module('app').factory("MyService", ["$http", function($http){

            return {
                getResourcesDataById : function(pId, fct){
                    // make the call
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/resources/data',
                        params: {
                            id : pId                        }
                    })

                    .then(function(data){
                        // callback function with the result
                        fct(data);
                    })
                }
            }
        }])

})(angular);
```